# open second created folder in c# code

Tags: c#

Is there a way to access the second generated folder?
I tried

```
var lastDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(path).GetDirectories("*",
    SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderByDescending(x => x.LastWriteTimeUtc).Second();
```

but it didn't work.

I'd appreciate it if you could give me a solution.

Comment: Use `.Skip(1).First()` instead of `.Second()`.

Comment: If you want the second one generated, you might want to use `x.CreationTimeUtc` instead of `LastWriteTimeUtc`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Skip(1)` to skip the first element and then use `FirstOrDefault()` to take the second element or default if there's none:

```
var lastDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(path).GetDirectories("*",
    SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderByDescending(x => x.LastWriteTimeUtc)
        .Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

or you can use `ElementAtOrDefault`:

```
var lastDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(path).GetDirectories("*",
        SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderByDescending(x => x.LastWriteTimeUtc)
            .ElementAtOrDefault(1);
```